# Linux Semaphore Lifecycle

Tags: linux, ipc, semaphore

I have an old C++ STL 11 program that uses a semaphore and a shared memory. It is running for many years like a charm (Debian 7). Its executed under root.

Now I migrated to a new server (Debian 9) and it runs under a non-root user.

The program is started in the background with nohup and &.

As soon I logout in the new environment the semaphore disappears (not anymore listed when ipcs).
But the shared memory is still available and the process is also executed what I do not understand. Why are not all IPC-elements are handled the same way?

Any ideas for that??

**EDIT**
If I start it with sudo the semaphore is owned by root and exists even if I logout.

Answer (score 1):

Any process that's started in the background by a shell will get SIGHUP when you log out.  If your process doesn't handle that, it will be terminated.

If you want to preserve a process that you've started this way, you can either use the `disown` shell builtin to avoid that or start the process with `nohup`.

The reason this succeeds when you run it as root is because your unprivileged user cannot signal a root-owned process and therefore the shell's attempt to do so fails silently.

The semaphore is, in this case, a red herring.

Comment: It is started with nohup and also is not terminated after logout. The semaphore is deleted. But the process is still running and the shared memory is not deleted.